# Дизайнер WPF отображает изменения вьюмодели только после того, как вручную запустишь сборку или убьешь процесс дизайнера

Tags: c#, wpf

Я создаю экземпляр вьюмодели непосредственно в разметке и привязываюсь к его же свойствам.

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestProperty}"/>
</Grid>
```

В конструкторе вьюмодели прописана инструкция

```cs
TestProperty = 12345;
```

Соответственно, это же значение отображается в соответствующем текстблоке.

Ранее, до моего вчерашнего перехода на версию 16.7.30517, при любом изменении этого значения в конструкторе дизайнер **сам** спустя не более 2 секунд менял значение в текстблоке. Правильнее даже сказать, что дело не столько во вьюмодели, сколько в самом механизме привязки, она не обновляется.

Сейчас же мне приходится вручную каждый прожимать <kbd>F6</kbd> и ждать сборки проекта, чтобы увидеть даже самые малые и незначительные изменения, то есть вместо условных двух секунд приходится тратить до десяти. Есть предположение, что где-то в настройках студии есть пункт "проверять изменения в реальном времени", который обновление отключило, но я такого так и не нашел

Comment: Уберите исполняемый код из конструктора вьюмодели, вынесите его в отдельный метод, и запускайте его например из события Window.Loaded. Проблема в том, что при привязке VM через xaml выполняется ее конструктор даже в дизайнере, поэтому там не должно быть ничего, что позволит стартовать тому, чего не должно быть в дизайнере.

Comment: @aepot до обновления дизайнер исправно обновлял данные даже при наличии исполняемого кода в конструкторе. Сейчас убрал весь исполняемый код из конструктора, да и сам конструктор, очистил-перезагрузил проект. Ничего не поменялось, данные не обновляются. Скажем, значение поля testField по умолчанию - 1, при изменении на 2 всё также требуется собрать проект, чтобы дизайнер обновил привязку к свойству TestField

Comment: Ну возможно баг в студии. Обычно в подобных случаях разработчики студии рекомендуют полную переустановку студии. В любом случае, если ничего не помогает, то лучше писать [сюда](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: А зачем вообще показывать в дизайнере реальные значения? Почему вообще не показывать заглушки с помощью `d:DesignInstance`?